# Change checkbox values on button click

Tags: iphone

I have a tableview with all cells having a button each. Each button is designed as a checkbox and has the functionalities of checkbox. I have a toolbar in the same view, and on the click of a toolbar button I need to change the value of all the checkboxes in the table. Right now I am not able to find a solution for this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How have u added buttons to cell? code might make things clearer.

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UIButton *checkBox = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        checkBox.tag = contact.contactID;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:checkBox];
        [checkBox setFrame:CGRectMake(6,14,20,20)];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your tool bar button click, Set a flag.According to the flag value, you perform the Reload tableView operation with your need data for the cells